Detecting and converting a number from a video (digital panel) into an actual number
Let's say I have video (mp4) of length 02:17:38 (hh:mm:ss), this video is a record of a temperature panel, as shown in the following image. How can I use mathematica to extract the temperature, given 3 parameters:
Starting time, ending time, and step length. Call them (startingtime, endingtime, steplength)


startingtime is the number of seconds (from the beginning of the video) where the temperature is not needed to be recorded. For example, if I set startingtime=5, then Mathematica should give first temperature at 00:00:05
ending time is the number of seconds (from the end of the video) where temperature is not needed to be recorded. For example, if I set endingtime=67, then Mathematica should give last reading at 02:16:31
steplength is the number of seconds between two consecutive readings.

Putting all together. Given a video with length 02:17:38
INPUTS:
startingtime=5;
endingtime=67;
steplength=18;

OUTOUTS:
{(00:00:05,24.2),(00:00:23,24.9),(00:00:41,24.6), and so on, (02:15:59,28.3),(02:16:17,28.5)}

So the next reading must be excluded because that will be at 02:16:35, but that does not meet the endingtime of 67.

I few things to note:

I have not try anything about this, because I am not an expert in mathematica, except that I know it is possible to do such a thing.

Due to size, I cannot provide such videos. But hopefully what I mean is very much clear, my English is not that good.

INPUTS and OUTPUTS are written above for illustration only of what I want, and can be in different formats, I am not strict about the output format, it will also be sufficient if the outputs where only temperatures (without times), like: 24.2,24.9,24.6,...,28.3,28.5

An idea, not sure if it is necessary to be considered: the code is to be programmed in a way it convert instants to images then use image processing to detect numbers then convert them as outputs.



Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

This is my general methodology:

Make a list of "reference" digit images.
Compare the digits in the image (by using ImageDistance) to the reference digits, and select the closest one.

Note that I also assume the image will always have data of the form XY.Z º C , (with X, Y, Z being digits 0-9) and I just find these three X,Y,Z values.
Making the reference digits
I first downloaded the digital clock symbol image for digits 0 - 9 from here
refNumbers = 
  Binarize@
   Import["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:\
ANd9GcTw5weHinnSVcB0cJFGWa6WvIp-MhuSKflKXg&s"];


I then split the image into the first row and second row:
id = ImageDimensions[refNumbers];
refRows = Flatten@ImagePartition[refNumbers, {id[[1]], id[[2]]/2}];


I now grab the image data, and split the image data whenever there are empty (all black) columns:
refDat = ImageData /@ refRows;
splitRefByColTot = SplitBy[Transpose@#, Total[#] > 0 &] & /@ refDat;

I then get the continuous regions with non-empty columns, and convert them back into images (giving us each digit as an individual image):
symbolRefData = ( Transpose /@ Select[#, Total@Flatten[#] > 0 &]) & /@
    splitRefByColTot;
symbolRefData = Flatten[symbolRefData, 1];
symbolImgs = Image /@ symbolRefData;


We don't need the semi-colon (:) at position 6, so I just drop that. I also use ImagePad with BorderDimensions to get just the digit part of each image:
(*delete colon at position 6*)
symbolImgs = Drop[symbolImgs, {6}];
(*only select where the number is*)
symbolImgs = ImagePad[#, -BorderDimensions[#, .07]] & /@ symbolImgs
(*shape all to same size*)


I now resize all of the reference digit images to be the same size. Note that this makes the 1 really thick and blurry because of how thin it originally is. This should not be an issue however, because this should also happen to our actual image digit if we ever get a 1 as well when we resize it:
refSize = ImageDimensions[symbolImgs[[1]]];
(*the "1" gets very blurred because it is so thin but this should \
also happen when we resize actual 1s*)
REFSYMBOLS = ImageResize[#, refSize] & /@ symbolImgs
REFSYMBOLS = Thread[REFSYMBOLS -> Range[0, 9]]


Finding the image digits
You could probably also use ColorDetect, but for this case I just use Binarize and delete small noisy components with DeleteSmallComponents:
img = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/7oGzdHRe.png"]
binThreshold = 0.5;
minSize = 200;
bin = Binarize[img, binThreshold ]


And now we follow the exact same methodology as we did for our reference digits to get our image digits:
clockPart = ImagePad[bin, -BorderDimensions[bin, .07]];
dat = ImageData[clockPart];
splitByColTot = SplitBy[Transpose@dat, Total[#] > 0 &];
symbolData = 
  Transpose /@ Select[splitByColTot, Total@Flatten[#] > 0 &];
symbolImgs = Image /@ symbolData;
(*resize to reference size*)
symbolImgs = ImageResize[#, refSize] & /@ symbolImgs;
(*drop c*)
symbolImgs = Most@symbolImgs;


And we find the nearest reference digit to each image digit. I found Nearest with its default DistanceFunction works well here (as an alternative, ImageDistance[#1, #2, DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance]& also works well):
 digsList = Nearest[valsList, symbolImgs] // Flatten;
(*{3, 3, 5}*)

And since we assume the number looks like XY.Z:
FromDigits[digsList]*0.1

(*33.5*)

Putting this all together
We define our REFSYMBOLS:
refNumbers = 
  Binarize@
   Import["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:\
ANd9GcTw5weHinnSVcB0cJFGWa6WvIp-MhuSKflKXg&s"];

id = ImageDimensions[refNumbers];
refRows = Flatten@ImagePartition[refNumbers, {id[[1]], id[[2]]/2}];
refDat = ImageData /@ refRows;

splitRefByColTot = SplitBy[Transpose@#, Total[#] > 0 &] & /@ refDat;
symbolRefData = ( Transpose /@ Select[#, Total@Flatten[#] > 0 &]) & /@
    splitRefByColTot;

symbolRefData = Flatten[symbolRefData, 1];
symbolImgs = Image /@ symbolRefData;

(*delete colon at position 6*)
symbolImgs = Drop[symbolImgs, {6}];

(*only select where the number is*)
symbolImgs = ImagePad[#, -BorderDimensions[#, .07]] & /@ symbolImgs;

(*shape all to same size*)
refSize = ImageDimensions[symbolImgs[[1]]];

(*the "1" gets very blurred because it is so thin but this should \
also happen when we resize actual 1s*)
REFSYMBOLS = ImageResize[#, refSize] & /@ symbolImgs;

REFSYMBOLS = Thread[REFSYMBOLS -> Range[0, 9]]

And a function that takes in an image, and returns the XY.Z value in the image based on the Nearest element of REFSYMBOLS:
returnClockDigs[img_] := 
 Module[{binThreshold = 0.5, minSize = 200, bin, clockPart, dat, 
   splitByColTot, symbolData, symbolImgs},
  bin = Binarize[img, binThreshold];
  bin = DeleteSmallComponents[bin, minSize];
  
  clockPart = ImagePad[bin, -BorderDimensions[bin, .07]];
  dat = ImageData[clockPart];
  
  splitByColTot = SplitBy[Transpose@dat, Total[#] > 0 &];
  symbolData = 
   Transpose /@ Select[splitByColTot, Total@Flatten[#] > 0 &];
  symbolImgs = Image /@ symbolData;
  
  (*resize to reference size*)
  symbolImgs = ImageResize[#, refSize] & /@ symbolImgs;
  (*drop c*)symbolImgs = Most@symbolImgs;
  
   digsList = Nearest[valsList, symbolImgs] // Flatten;
  FromDigits[digsList]*0.1
  ]

returnClockDigs can then be mapped to whatever frames you want of a video (which can be extracted at given timestamps by using VideoExtractFrames )
Validation
I have a whole bunch of digital numbers from when I was doing an analysis of this question on reddit.
For some reason, VideoExtractFrames gives me an VideoExtractFrames::tmbnd message despite the fact that I'm grabbing valid timestamps. So instead I extract all frames, and grab a frame every 1 s based on the known frame rate:
vide = Import["DIR_TO_MY_VIDEO"]
vfl = VideoFrameList[video, All];
frameRate = 60;
jump = 1*frameRate;
frameIndices = Range[1, vfl // Dimensions // First, jump];
testFrames = Part[vfl, frameIndices];

(*collage of the test frames*)
ImageCollage[testFrames]


These test images have already been binarized from my previous analysis on them. I now copy by hand their true values:
trueVals = {0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 22, 30, 38, 48, 58, 67, 76, 85,
    94, 102, 118, 128, 136, 144, 152, 161, 170, 178, 186, 194, 202, 
   210, 218, 225, 233, 241, 249, 256, 263, 270, 277, 285, 292, 298, 
   306, 312, 319, 325, 331, 337, 344, 349, 355, 360, 364, 368, 370, 
   372, 373, 373, 373, 373, 373};

before we apply our function to it, we need to slightly modify it because these numbers aren't of the form XY.Z, they are just instead raw digits:
returnClockDigsTESTING[img_] := 
 Module[{binThreshold = 0.5, minSize = 200, bin, clockPart, dat, 
   splitByColTot, symbolData, symbolImgs},
  bin = Binarize[img, binThreshold];
  bin = DeleteSmallComponents[bin, minSize];
  
  clockPart = ImagePad[bin, -BorderDimensions[bin, .07]];
  dat = ImageData[clockPart];
  
  splitByColTot = SplitBy[Transpose@dat, Total[#] > 0 &];
  symbolData = 
   Transpose /@ Select[splitByColTot, Total@Flatten[#] > 0 &];
  symbolImgs = Image /@ symbolData;
  (*resize to reference size*)
  symbolImgs = ImageResize[#, refSize] & /@ symbolImgs;
  
  
  digsList = Nearest[valsList, symbolImgs] // Flatten;
  FromDigits[digsList]
  ]

Now we are ready to test:
results = (returnClockDigsTESTING /@ testFrames)
(* {0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 22, 30, 38, 48, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 102,
118, 128, 136, 144, 152, 161, 170, 178, 186, 194, 202, 210, 218, 225, 
233, 241, 249, 256, 263, 270, 277, 285, 292, 298, 306, 312, 319, 325, 
331, 337, 344, 349, 355, 360, 364, 368, 370, 372, 373, 373, 373, 373, 
373} *)

Comparing this to our true values, we get all of them right :
results == trueVals

(*True*)

I am actually already pretty satisfied with this performance, and this should definitely be able to work for your application needs.

For the image provided TextRecognize works. My recipe is extracting the blue channel, then trim the image {{30, 160}, {380, 350}}, resize the image to about 80 pixel witdh, binarize (level ~0.3), apply a blurr with a gaussian filter (2 pixel) and then use TextRecognize. With ToExpression you will get the the numbers. However, the result depends on the region of interest you trim to and on the binarization level. It may not be stable throughout your full video.
For the timing I would use the frame rate and frame numbers to get the needed time span. I would resize the video first.

@Eisbär that's nice, I'll try it later. I've kind of given up on ever using TextRecognize because in my past experience it's been extremely sensitive to input pre-processing; it's always seemed to me you have to perfectly "tailor" the input for it, and each tailoring only works for a limited set of inputs, and then you have to change your pre-processing methodology again if the inputs change in characteristics too much.

I am with you. Mostly, the gaussian filter helped to stabilize the result.

TextRecognize is just tesseract with a small subset of tesseract's parameter. Its success depends strongly on removal of background and margins, exact horizontal orientation and some dilation or erosions of the text. The results depend on resolution and language options
Here I copy the picture

  bw = ColorNegate[Binarize[bild]]   

The cropping can be done by double click the image and use the crop tool

Finally we use a dilated image and TextRecognize for "Character".
Results depend on image size
  TextRecognize[Dilation[ImageResize[txb, 800], 4], "Character"]
     { "3", "3", "5", "}", ":"}  

   TextRecognize[Dilation[ImageResize[txb, 1600], 4], "Character"]
     {"3", "3", ".", "5", "}", ":"}

For further research see eg.
tesseract and TextRecognize
